# Centering a fixed width element that's wider than a fluid parent?

Tags: html, css

So, I just discovered this today and I couldn't find it this solution anywhere on Stackoverflow, so I thought I'd share it. Let me know if it's been posted somewhere else and I'll mark it as duplicate.

As far as I know centering an element wider than it's parent is a fairly common problem, the only solutions I've come across make use of Javascript, which turns out as a lengthy, messy bit of code that's annoying to maintain across lots of elements using this functionality.

The problem HTML:

```
<div class="container-fluid" >
    <div class="center-me-fixed">
        <span> Center </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container-fluid {
    max-width: 400px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display:block;
    margin:auto;   
}

.center-me-fixed {
    width: 500px;
    height:50px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution:

Use absolute positioning on the child you need to center, mess with the left/right values and set margin to auto like so:

CSS:

```
.center-me-fixed {
    position:absolute;
    left: -1000%;
    right: -1000%;
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    width: 500px;
    height: 50px;
}
```

Make sure the parent's container position is relative:

```
.container-fluid {
    position: relative;
     width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display:block;
    margin:auto;   
}
```

And that's it! I'm not sure how this works, if someone could explain that would be cool.

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CRR5C/)**

Answer (score 0):

I searched on the web and the best solutions i've found is this 
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/videma/hZgf6/2/)
css:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

div.container-fluid {
  border:1px solid blue;
  max-width:400px;
  margin:0px auto;
  min-height: 100%;
}
div.container-fluid .center-me-fixed {
  position:relative;
  right:50%;
  text-align:center;
}
div.container-fluid .center-me-fixed span  {
  border:1px solid green;
  width: 500px;
  height:50px;
  display:inline-block;
  margin-right:-100%;
}
```

html:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="center-me-fixed">
    <span>
      this should be centered
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

If this solution does not suit your needs, i apologize for making you lose time.